# My .writelines() function is not working in python

Tags: python

I am new to Python (and coding in general). So, please help me out a little bit on this one.

Code:

```
f = open("info.txt", "w")
l = ["Apples", "Android", "Coffee"]
f.writelines(l)
f.close()
f = open("info.txt", "r")
s = f.read()
print(s)
```

The output looks like this:
[image: Output]

OR:

```
ApplesAndroidCoffee

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: what is your expected output then?

Comment: Note [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.writelines): "Write a list of lines to the stream. Line separators are not added, so it is usual for each of the lines provided to have a line separator at the end."

Answer (score 2):

`writelines` will not supply newline characters for you, so if the strings do not contain them already then you will have to add them.

You could do:

```
f.writelines(line + '\n' for line in l)
```